# How to convert a promise in protractor to a string

Tags: jasmine, protractor, chai, chai-as-promised

I am a bit new to Protractor and Jasmine, and I am trying to check if a list of elements that I have fetched using getText() contains a particular element:

Consider the following elements

```
var productNameElements = element.all(by.css('.table-row')).getText();
    elementToBeSearched = element(by.css('.table-row .table-row-child(1)')).getText();
```

Now since both the variables above would return a promise, therefore by doing:

```
expect(productNameElements).to.eventually.contain(elementToBeSearched);
```

would fail, and it does fail.

Therefore, I believe that converting `elementToBeSearched` into a string would be beneficial and would make my life easier. Please suggest a solution on how can I convert a `getText()` promise to a string. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Lets say that the element is ele. So the way you should resolve the promise is-

```
ele.getText().then(function(str){
expect(someOtherElement.getText()).toBe(str);
})
```

The .then resolves the promise for you. You can confirm the string by puting a `console.log(str)`before you compare with `expect`.
PS: The promise inside the expect parenthesis is automatically resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was mostly similar:

productNameElements = element.all(by.css('.table-row')).getText().then(function(name) {
expect(productNameElements).to.eventually.contain(name);
});

This seems to have done the trick for me as I also checked the value of 'name' using console logging

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me:

```
let txt = (await elementToBeSearched.then()).toString();
```